# QlikView File not found error Cannot open file

Tags: excel, error-handling, runtime-error, load, qlikview

I am trying to load data into QlikView Load Script.
The file is an Excel file.
First it loaded and then it returns the following message:

File not found error

Cannot open file:
System error: Filesystem::FindEx non existing dir C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a couple of suggestions:

1. make sure your path is enclosed in brackets [].  so if your path is c:\folder\excel.xlsx, make sure you have [c:\folder\excel.xlsx]
2. if your file is located on a shared drive, use the unc path instead of the local path: [\\server\share\folder\excel.xlsx]